# Sammy.js - Get path from within route

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I'm learning Sammy.js and using it to build a mini-application on top of a REST API I'm working on. I couldn't find this immediately, and I am probably missing something.

I'm using routes like:

```
this.get("/databases/:name", function () { ... });
```

I basically want to take the route path and pass it along to my REST API, since they largely match up anyways. I've inspected `this` within the callback, and found a property called `path` that contains the full path, including the filename. (i.e. `/index.html#/databases/foo`)

All I care about is what comes after the `#`, and I wonder if there is something baked in so I don't have to use `this.path.split("#")[1]`.

Comment: Any reason you can't look at `window.location.hash`?

Comment: Actually, there's no reason I can't do that. Good call! (put it as an answer, I'll accept) ... kinda feel silly for not thinking of that myself... :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just look at [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties) and strip off the leading `#`. That should be pretty much the same as pulling information out of `this.path`.